# Django how does Django know which formset is which

Tags: python, django

1. Assuming I have a model that directly correspond to a ModelFormset.
2. Assuming three instances of the model are saved in the database.
3. Assuming I loaded the ModelFormset with initial data = the three instances
4. Now I render the ModelFormset on a page for users to modify.
5. After modification, users click on submit. How do I know which one of the ModelFormset correspond to which instance of the Model saved in the database?

Update:

I was reading this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets-initial-data

In this example, the initial data was provide manually. Assuming if the the initial data was passed in like this:

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=...)
formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[
    model_to_dict(article)
])
```

When this `formset` is sent to the template, is article's id preserved in the rendered HTML? If not, then how does Django know which article it should update if modifications to the article has been made and submitted?

Comment: Please show your code. You probably shouldn't be using the `initial` argument, but `queryset`.

Comment: if you have an existing instance in `ModelForm` (or in a set of them inside `ModelFormset`), then there's a hidden field with the value of primary key for the record. Each `ModelForm` has also an unique suffix, which helps distinguish which fields belongs to the same model

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I think you could repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing instance in `ModelForm` (or in a set of them inside ModelFormset), then there's a hidden field with the value of the primary key for the record.

Each `ModelForm` has also a unique suffix for each the field, which helps distinguish which fields belongs to the same model.

Comment: What if the modelformset is deleted? Is it also marked as deleted in a hidden field?

Comment: I dont understand your question. For deleting the records in modelformset there is a checkbox marked by label "delete" (or "remove" or something) at each row. When you check it, then the record will be deleted on the form's submission.

Comment: I wonder if the deleted item was just 'marked' as delete. Let's say we rendered two formset. One is deleted by the user, when the data is submitted, will you still receive two formsets back with one marked as deleted or will you only receive one formset back?